# Visual Studio COM access

Tags: python, visual-studio, com

Is it possible to control Visual Studio like you can control Excel through the Python COM API?

I'm trying to kick off a build through COM (don't ask!)

An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Agreed.. But don't bother trying MSBuild if you have any setup projects in your solution - it won't build them.

Comment: Kicking off a build through COM is just an example. There are more things I'd like to do like track the current file or open a specific class. But I'd like to do this without writing an add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See the Visual Studio SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441%28VS.80%29.aspx

There are C# wrappers for the COM objects, but the underlying technology is COM.

Comment: Any specific links to code? I just see references to references.